# Turning Percentile_cont/disc (Median) into scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Editing this since turns out we were trying to recreate the wheel.

The below works perfectly in determining the median. Now, how would we go about converting into a function so that we can call median(column) instead of having to do the below each time. Below does the trick:

```
   select percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by n) over (PARTITION BY [column1]),

   from t;
```

AHH - I see. Is it possible to groupby where it calcs the median only across where column1 = a,b,c so output would be

```
 A median of values with A identifier
 B median of values with B identifier
 C median of values with C identifier
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just usetthe [`percentile_cont()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`percentile_disc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window functions:

```
select percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by n) over (),
       percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by n) over ()      
from t;
```

There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: How would I go about creating that into a function? I saw these responses with the percentile_cont but am way to new to building functions.

Comment: @PDFnewb . . . You don't need to create your own function.  You can use the ANSI/ISO standard `percentile_XXX` functions to do what you want.

Comment: what do you mean? Perhaps i'm confused as to how percentile_xxx would calc the median

Comment: @PDFnewb . . . There are two examples in the answer.

Comment: I didn't want to delete but yeah i figured it out. Was being stupid. Any idea how I could get the median

      A median of values with A identifier
      B median of values with B identifier
      C median of values with C identifier